# PostgreSQL - Get all rows with min max value

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, datetime, where-clause

I have a PostgreSQL table, I have a column in the table for unix_time of type bigint.

When a new row is added to the table, the time stamp is added to the unix_time column.

I'm busy writing a Python script to extract all rows between time A and time B, my current solution is iterating over every single row from the first to the last row in the table with a while loop.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Is there a way for me to select only the specific rows that have values in a given range - or rows that have a value greater than or equal to a given integer?

Comment: Yes: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE tscol BETWEEN ... AND ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would are describing a `where` clause:

```
select *
from mytable
where unix_time >= $1 and unix_time < $2
```

`$1` and `$2` are parameters to the query, that represent the bounds of the interval you want to filter on.

You might want to adjust the inequalities for your actual case; this uses half-open intervals, which is a widely used solution. If you want an interval inclusive on both sides, you can also use `between`:

```
where unix_time between $1 and $2
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the BETWEEN clause.  Search for some nice examples.  Here is a page.

[https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/using-the-postgres-between-sql-operator-740#:~:text=In%20PostgreSQL%2C%20BETWEEN%20is%20typically%20used%20as%20part,that%20match%20values%20found%20between%20x%20and%20y](https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/using-the-postgres-between-sql-operator-740#:%7E:text=In%20PostgreSQL%2C%20BETWEEN%20is%20typically%20used%20as%20part,that%20match%20values%20found%20between%20x%20and%20y).

```
SELECT t_name_product
FROM Products
WHERE c_price BETWEEN x AND y;
```

OR
SELECT t_name_product
FROM Products
WHERE c_price > x AND c_price <= y;

Remember you get different results if you use AND or OR.

For your last question regarding greater than or equal:

```
SELECT t_name_product 
FROM Products
WHERE Price >= 100;
```

Comment: This page shows you comparison between dates: 

https://www.educba.com/postgresql-compare-date/

Comment: Much appreciated!